# file_picker but for directories in ios and android

Tags: flutter, filepicker

My flutter app uses the [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) to retrieve a file from dropbox, google drive, etc. The user then edits stuff in the file, and along with other files, creates a zip of them.

My goal is to allow the user to browse a folder location in any of these, like dropbox, google drive, etc. Just like in the file_picker. However, the file_picker library does not appear to allow for picking directories in these 3p services, just files. I am not able to find another library that allows me to pick a 3p service, and save a file to a chosen directory as seamlessly as the file_picker allows for choosing a file.

Am I missing something? My only next idea is to integrate each of these 3p services myself, and use their equivalent listDirectories() methods to allow a user to select a location. This is a decent bit of effort though comparatively, and involves a lot of developer time.

Comment: There's a directory picker in file_picker package.
https://github.com/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker/wiki/API#-getdirectorypath
https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker

String? selectedDirectory = await FilePicker.platform.getDirectoryPath();

if (selectedDirectory == null) {
  // User canceled the picker
}
https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker

Answer (score 0):

There's a directory picker in [file_picker](https://github.com/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker/wiki/API#-getdirectorypath) at github and
[file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) at pub.dev.

There's an example in the docs.

```
String? selectedDirectory = await FilePicker.platform.getDirectoryPath();
 if (selectedDirectory == null) { 
// User canceled the picker 
}
```

Comment: This works for local to device paths, but not if I want a path to a dropbox directory, or any other 3p directory.

Comment: Oh ok, got it. Will look into it, if I find a solution, will post it. Thanks :)